# ADB Android Studio Ubuntu ERROR : Unable to detect adb version, adb output: /home/hamid/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/

Tags: adb

ADB in Android Studio (Ubuntu) ERROR : Unable to detect adb version, adb output: /home/hamid/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1: /home/hamid/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Comment: Any one can help plz

Comment: When does this error occur? What did you do? How did you install it? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: i have same issue on windows 7 x64 .. i also installed genymotion. but none of emulators showing in target deployment dialogue. any idea for windows ?

Answer (score 29):

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Got same error after update Android Studio and then Android SDK.

### **[SOLUTION : Downgrade /platform-tools folder]**

1. Download this arch. : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip
2. Go to your Android SDK folder
3. Remove old /platform-tools
4. Insert downloaded from link above

Hope this help you.

**[UPDATED]**

Forgot specify that Ubuntu is 32 bit

Comment: Thanks buddy, it gone like flash! Thank you so much ..!! I solved my problem

Comment: This solved my problem too, on Linux Mint 17.1 32-bit

Comment: Thanks Elia, this worked on my 32bit Ubuntu 15.10, however when Android Studio updated the component it reverted to the 64bit version so no more updating of this component for me!.

Comment: Android Studio wanted an update which put the same bug back in. To fix, instead of replacing entire /platform-tools, instead, I just extracted adb by itself and that worked!

Comment: Excellent advice. Also solves the problem on Ubuntu 16.04 on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: Thank you , it solved that problem ( Ubuntu 16.04 32bit ). I am programming more than 30 years in various languages and IDEs , I have never seen such a mess as Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

This happened only for 32 bits linux platform.

The Android SDK Platform-tools Rev. 23.1.0 doesn't support 32 bits.

Some explanations are given (and asked) here :

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=ubuntu&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=-id&id=196866

Greatings,

Eric